# Telerik DropDown List not populating correctly

Tags: c#, telerik, blazor

My razor code icludes this telerik dropdown list:

```
<TelerikDropDownList Data="@BkAccounts" TextField="@(nameof(BkAccounts.DisplayField))" ValueField="@(nameof(BkAccounts.BIC))" Value=1 ></TelerikDropDownList>
```

It points to this class:

```
public class BkAccounts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Iban { get; set; }
    public string BIC{ get; set; }
    public string DisplayField{ get { return this.Iban + " - " + this.BIC; } }
}
```

If I write it this way, the dropdown list does not populate correctly.

If I change it this way:

```
<TelerikDropDownList Data="@BkAccounts" TextField="@(nameof(BkAccounts.DisplayField))" ValueField="@(nameof(BkAccounts.Id))" Value=1 ></TelerikDropDownList>
```

It works fine.

Actually, I want to remove the Id field from this BkAccounts class but I am not able to have the DDL to populatecorrectly.
What did I miss?
According to Telerik doc, TextField can accept a string field so it should not be a format problem...

Edit:
the difference between the 2 snippets stands here:
ValueField="@(nameof(BkAccounts.BIC)  ---> does NOT populate
ValueField="@(nameof(BkAccounts.Id)  ---> populates like a charm

Comment: Did you try changing  Value=1 to Value="1" as value is a string field now?

Comment: The problem still exists in 2023 if you use ValueExpression and ValueChanged instead of @bind-Value. The Value-Parameter alone does not initialize the display value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Telerik forum:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/telerikdropdownlist-throwing-a-system-invalidcastexception-when-valuefield-is-a-string#tnrnhB1ghkmWxEUE24wUhA

I needed to add into my TelerikDropDownList code:
@bind-Value=@SelectedBankAccount
and declare it as a string property into theviewmodel

Answer (score -1):

I start to strongly suspect that the issue is on Telerik side.
Here is their sample TelerikDropDownList code from 
https://demos.telerik.com/blazor-ui/dropdownlist/overview

```
@page "/dropdownlist/overview"
@page "/dropdownlist/index"

@using TelerikBlazorDemos.Shared

<div class="example-box-wrapper">
    <div class="example">
        <div class="mb-4">T-Shirt size:</div>
        <TelerikDropDownList Data="@Data"
                             @bind-Value=@SelectedSizeMetric
                             PopupHeight=""
                             DefaultText="Select your T-shirt size"
                             ValueField="SizeMetric" TextField="SizeText">
        </TelerikDropDownList>
    </div>

    <div class="ml-4">
        Selected Size Number: <strong>@SelectedSizeMetric</strong>
    </div>
</div>

@code  {
    public IEnumerable<Size> Data { get; set; }
    public bool AllowCustom { get; set; } = true;
    public int? SelectedSizeMetric { get; set; }
    public string SelectedSize { get; set; }

    public class Size
    {
        public string SizeText { get; set; }
        public int? SizeMetric { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        List<Size> sizes = new List<Size>();

        sizes.Add(new Size()
        {
            SizeText = "X-Small",
            SizeMetric = 3
        });

        sizes.Add(new Size()
        {
            SizeText = "Small",
            SizeMetric = 6
        });

        sizes.Add(new Size()
        {
            SizeText = "Medium",
            SizeMetric = 8
        });

        sizes.Add(new Size()
        {
            SizeText = "Large",
            SizeMetric = 10
        });

        sizes.Add(new Size()
        {
            SizeText = "X-Large",
            SizeMetric = 12
        });

        Data = sizes.AsQueryable();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

It works fine as it is.
But if I change:

```
ValueField="SizeMetric" //int type
```

for:

```
ValueField="SizeText"  //string type
```

it nolonger works...
I get:
System.InvalidCastException : 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'.'

Comment: I also needed to change:
public int? SelectedSizeMetric { get; set; }

to

public string SelectedSizeMetric { get; set; }

to make it work.